# AspectJ weave external dependency code, repackage jar and force dependency users to use it

Tags: java, maven, aop, aspectj, hikaricp

Let's say I have a common multi-module maven project which modules are used as dependencies across bunch of the projects, I want to weave my Aspects into Hikari dependency classes and make this logic in the on of these common modules and make those common multi-module users to have woven Hikari jar. As I guess the following steps are required:

1. Compile code with aspects (did that)
2. Repackage external jar with code from 1)
3. Somehow force all the projects having this common dependency to use this repackaged jar.

I am kind of confused of steps 2-3 possibility and didn't manage to find any reliable guides or doc references. Is it even possible in the way all the changes will be seamless for dependency users? Project to look at or play with : [git-repo](https://github.com/setofaces/aspectj-maven-sof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I do believe `AspectJ` is not proper choice for this particular case, since you are using `spring-framework` you may build more elegant solution using `BeanPostProcessor` and [`datasource-proxy` project](https://github.com/jdbc-observations/datasource-proxy), smth. like:

```java
public class DiagDataSourcePostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(@NonNull Object bean, @NonNull String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (!(bean instanceof DataSource)) {
            return bean;
        }

        ProxyDataSourceBuilder builder = ProxyDataSourceBuilder.create(beanName, (DataSource) bean);
        builder.listener(new JdbcLifecycleEventListenerAdapter() {

            public void beforeClose(MethodExecutionContext executionContext) {
                if (executionContext.getTarget() instanceof Connection) {
                    // some logic here
                }
            }

            public void afterGetConnection(MethodExecutionContext executionContext) {
                // some logic here
            }


        });
        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

```java
@Bean
public static BeanPostProcessor diagDataSourcePostProcessor() {
    return new DiagDataSourcePostProcessor();
}
```

---

As regards to your aspectj project it contains some smells which actually prevent you from achieving your goal:

1. you should avoid defining plugins and dependencies in aggregate pom's - in your case you have turned `aspectj` module into "application" however that should be a "library", so, aggregate pom (`demo`) should look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>aspectj-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>aspectj</module>
        <module>some-app</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

2. since the purpose of `aspectj` module is to build some kind of "enhanced" version of `HikariCP` (**in case of compile-time weaving**), it should not "depend" on `HikariCP` from "library observer" perspective, otherwise application classpath will contain two versions of `HikariCP` library: "enhanced" and the original one, so, `aspectj` pom should look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <weaveDependencies>
                    <weaveDependency>
                        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                    </weaveDependency>
                </weaveDependencies>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

3. and, I believe, that is clear the application module (`some-app`) should depend on `aspectj` module and do not depended on `HikariCP`, so, finally we get:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-app</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Unfortunately, the configuration above is unreliable, the problem is it does work within maven context but there is no chance it will work smoothly in IDE.

Comment: Great answer, man, thanks!

Comment: Andrey B. Panfilov explained the details very well, but the short answer to the question in the subject is: **No,** you cannot force downstream users to use your dependency instead of the original one. This would be a huge security problem. Imagine, I create a custom version of a popular library with a backdoor and would by some magical means contrive to the whole world to use mine instead of the original one. That does not make sense. So, in Maven the user is in control of which dependencies she pulls into her project.

Comment: That is why the exclusion for the original was necessary, as it was already pulled into your project as a transitive dependency. As for getting this to work smoothly in an IDE, I think this is possible. Exclusions should be respected by IDEs. Just do not try to do everything in one big project. If you create the woven dependency separately and `mvn install|deploy` it, then in the consuming project this limits the possibility that the IDE falsely pulls in the original (`provided` scope) dependency into the classpath when running the projcet from the IDE instead of from the command line.

Comment: If, instead of using compile-time weaving, you just let your project depend on the aspect library and use load-time weaving instead, it would also work from the IDE, but of course at the expense of configuring LTW. The advantage would be that users would have a choice to run the project with or without aspect enhancement, simply by (de-)activating LTW. Each variant is a teade-off, it depends on the use case's context.

Comment: It works, I just tried: I pulled out the aspect module into its own project, using _spring-boot-starter-parent_ as a parent directly, built it with `mvn clean install`, used it as a regular (external) dependency in the application module, excluded the original library, and it works perfectly, also in the IDE. Even jumping to Hikari classes from the IDE leads to the woven ones in the dependency.

Comment: Note to myself and everyone else wondering why Andrey used the `provided` scope: It makes the dependency non-transitive. Very nice, indeed. Read [this Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes) for reference.

Comment: @kriegaex I definitely can't speak for every IDE, however I can say `IntelliJ` do not support the most of maven "tricks" when we are talking about "My goal is to press green play button opposite to class/method and I expect it should work smoothly", `aspectj-maven-plugin` is not the only case there, `maven-shade-plugin`, `maven-dependency-plugin` and the most code generators are problematic as well. As for me the rule of thumb is following: if green button does not want to play that means I'm doing something wrong and my activities are just wasting the time of other developers.

Comment: so, in case of CTW the best option is to move module to another dedicated project, on the other hand, there is a great change that LTW will work "as expected", at least `IntelliJ` has a special handling of  `maven-surefire-plugin` configuration.

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, and it works as I described it. Of course, splitting into two projects is a workaround for imperfections in IDEA, but it is viable and straightforward. To keep an aspect library separate from consuming projects (plural!), makes sense  for modularisation reasons, even without the need for a workaround. It is a special case to define an aspect library to be used by a single project only. With Hikari in this concrete case, I would also argue that the aspect-enhanced version should be useful in other projects, too.

Comment: What you mentioned about Surefire is the support for VM arguments to the test VM, including (in this case) `-javaagent:`. Just be careful not to put the same parameters into the Maven Failsafe config, as IDEA then will use both, duplicating VM parameters, which is quite annoying.

Comment: IntelliJ contains a special handling of `maven-surefire-plugin` and `maven-failsafe-plugin`: [MavenJUnitPatcher.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/maven/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/idea/maven/execution/MavenJUnitPatcher.java), I do something similar in [SpringBootPatcher.java](https://github.com/andreybpanfilov/spring-boot-patcher/blob/master/src/tel/panfilov/intellij/plugin/springboot/SpringBootPatcher.java), so, LTW has a good chance to work smoothly.